# how to check start range, end range, date range covered by data

Tags: python

i want to know how can i get the start date, end date and date range covered by data.

```
user_id gender  address store_id    trans_id    timestamp   item_id quantity    dollar
0   101981  F   E   2860    818463  2000-11-01  4.710000e+12    1   37
1   101981  F   E   2861    818464  2000-11-01  4.710000e+12    1   17
2   101981  F   E   2862    818465  2000-11-01  4.710000e+12    1   23
3   101981  F   E   2863    818466  2000-11-01  4.710000e+12    1   41
4   101981  F   E   2864    818467  2000-11-01  4.710000e+12    8   288
```

Comment: Thanks alot.
can you plz also guide about this
Are there items that are more commonly sold in bulk (quantity greater than 1)? 
How do quantity and volume tend to change over the course of the day (hour by hour)?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Convert timestamp to pandas datetime object
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

# Sort dataframe by date
df = df.sort_values(by='timestamp', ascending=False)

# Start date
print(df['timestamp'].min())
# End date
print(df['timestamp'].max())
# Date range is just between minimum and maximum
```